# Is there a way to use the React Link tag outside of a js file?

Tags: html, reactjs, hyperlink, navbar, jsx

I'm trying to use the Link from react so my pages don't refresh each time I click something in my Navbar, but I can't figure out how to get the Link element to work without having it inside of a JS file inside a Router. I wanted to use this for my Navbar and I have my Navbar in the index.html file because it should be there on every page so I did not want to have it inside every component. I tried pulling the Navbar out and putting it in its own component and adding that to the router, but that didn't work either. I have my App.js file attached, and the NavBar component is a bit large so I won't attatch the whole thing, but there is a small snippet just to show how I am trying to use the Link. The error I get is **Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use Link outside a Router.** Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```
import NavBar from './NavBar';

function App(){
    const element = (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar />
          {/* <nav>
            <Link to="/home" className="nav-link">Home</Link>
          </nav> */}
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                <Route path="/stocks" component={StockSearch}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <Route path="/*" component={PageNotFound}/>
              </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
      </div>

    );
    return element;
}

export default App;
```

Below is what my NavBar stuff looks like:

```
<li className="nav-item">
      <Link to="/stocks" className="nav-link">Stock Service</Link>
</li>
```

Comment: It looks like you have `Navbar />` rendered in App.js inside the `Router` instead of `index.html` you have mentioned in the question

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update my question when I changed my code a bit. I pulled it out of the index and put it in its own component, and added that to the router but that will not work either.